# How can I order Site Groups?

Tags: order

I have this query that lists out the site groups:

`craft.app.sites.getAllGroups()`

How can I order the result? Ideally I'd like to add a custom field to the Site Groups entry, but it doesn't seem Craft supports that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by being specific about the order I want the site groups to appear - through twig filtering and array merging. Since I actually need a specific sorting, and there are no custom fields available for Site Groups, I see no other way (though I realize I can do this with a custom filter or similar):

```
{% set allGroups = craft.app.sites.getAllGroups()|filter(group => group.sites|length > 0) %}
{% set siteGroupA = allGroups|filter(group => group.id == 3) %}
{% set siteGroupB = allGroups|filter(group => group.id == 4) %}
{% set siteGroupC = allGroups|filter(group => group.id == 1) %}
{% set siteGroupD = allGroups|filter(group => group.id == 2) %}
{% set orderedGroups = siteGroupA|merge(siteGroupB)|merge(siteGroupC)|merge(siteGroupD) %}

{% for siteGroup in orderedGroups %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Site groups are automatically sorted alphabetically in the interface, and `craft.app.sites.getAllGroups()` should return them in alphabetical order as well. Beyond that, site groups don't support a manual sort order or custom fields, so you will need to find a different solution.

Answer (score 1):

`getAllGroups()` isn't actually a query per-se. It returns a [`MemoizableArray`](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/base/MemoizableArray.php) which--while it does have a couple of query-ish methods--is essentially an array that implements a memoizing caching layer.

You can sort it yourself if you like; the easiest way is probably to make a [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#available-methods) out of it, and use [`sortBy()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-sortby) or the like.